# Gradle build - Maven Modello

Tags: maven, gradle, modello

I have a Maven build which uses maven-modello (1.4) to generate Java classes/XSD's etc. from an description file (modello file). I'm searching for a possible solution in Gradle to solve the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't test it, but can something like that do the trick:

```
import org.codehaus.modello.Modello

// Dependencies
buildscript {
  repositories {
    mavenCentral()
  }
  dependencies {
    classpath 'org.codehaus.modello:modello-maven-plugin:1.5'
  }
}

// Execution
task modello << {
  buildDir.mkdirs()
  file("$projectDir/models").eachFile { modelFile ->
    if (modelFile.name.endsWith('.mdo')) {
      new Modello().generate(modelFile.newReader(), generator, parameters)
    }
  }
}

// Configuration
modello.ext {
  generator = 'java'
  parameters = new Properties()  
  parameters.'modello.output.directory' = buildDir.absoluteFile
  parameters.'modello.version' = '1.5'
  parameters.'modello.package.with.version' = false
  parameters.'modello.output.useJava5' = true
  parameters.'modello.output.encoding' = 'UTF-8'
}
```